# PHP Magic __invoke upon object-property of a class

Tags: php, class, invoke, magic-methods, chainability

Consider this class arrangement - and in particular the magic function __invoke:

```
class Barman {  
    public function __construct() {
        // .. .constructor stuff - whatever
    }

    public function makeDrink() {
        return "vodka martini, shaken";
    }   
}

class Bar { 
    private $arr_barmen = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->arr_barmen['john'] = new Barman();
    }

   public function __invoke($barman_id) {
      echo "I have been invoked";
      return $this->arr_barmen[$barman_id];
   }

   public function aBarFunc($param) {
      return "yes it worked ," .$param;
   }
}

class Foo {

    public $myBar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->myBar = new Bar();
    }

}
```

I want to write syntax like this

```
$company = new Foo();
$company->myBar('john')->makeDrink();
```

*Preferred result:
"vodka martini, shaken"*

**Actual result:

"Call to undefined method Foo::myBar()"**

Invoking myBar() with the magic method should return a barman Object upon which you can call any of the barman's public methods

*But now consider this (which does work)*

```
$company = new Foo();
$myBar = $company->myBar;
$drink = $myBar('john')->makeDrink();
echo $drink;

// Result:
// I have been invoked 
// vodka martini, shaken
```

So what's going on? I don't like that workaround - it's not sleek. 
I need it to work this way:

$company->myBar('john')->makeDrink();

Please help? :-)

Comment: Can you clarify what PHP version you're using?\ (it is relevant here).

Comment: PHP 7.2 in this case

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can just add braces around it:

```
$company = new Foo();
$drink = ($company->myBar)('john')->makeDrink();
echo $drink; // vodka martini, shaken
```

Answer (score 3):

This is being caused by an ambiguity in the call you're trying to make:

```
$company->myBar('john')->makeDrink();
```

Because `myBar` is a property, the PHP interpreter isn't expecting it to be callable. It is parsing it as an attempt to call a method called `myBar()` which doesn't exist, and is thus throwing the error.

The direct way to resolve this is to clarify the ambiguity for the interpreter. You do this by adding curly braces around the property, as follows:

```
$company->{myBar}('john')->makeDrink();
```

The code is now explicit that `myBar` is a property and should be accessed as such, but that it contains a value that is callable and that you wish to make that call.

This whole topic is complicated (slightly) by the fact that PHP 5.x and PHP 7.x behave differently with regard to how they default to handling these kinds of ambiguity. PHP 7 changed the defaults in order to correct some internal inconsistencies within the language. The result is that in situations like this where you have an ambiguity, if you want your code to work across both PHP 5.x and 7.x, you should always use the braces to explicitly define how you want it to work, regardless of whether your code works for you without them.

There is some documentation about this change in [the PHP 7.0 upgrade notes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php), although the examples given don't cover your exact situation.

Answer (score 1):

To attain chaining you have to return the Barman object in invoke.

```
class Barman {

    public function __construct() {
        // .. .constructor stuff - whatever
    }

    public function makeDrink() {
        return "vodka martini, shaken";
    }

}

class Bar {

    private $arr_barmen = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->arr_barmen['john'] = new Barman();
    }

    public function __invoke($barman_id) {
        echo "I have been invoked";
        return $this->arr_barmen[$barman_id] = new Barman();
    }

    public function aBarFunc($param) {
        return "yes it worked ," . $param;
    }

}

class Foo {

    public $myBar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->myBar = new Bar();
    }
    // create a function with variable name to invoke the object 
    public function myBar($name) {
        $mybar = $this->myBar;
        return $mybar($name);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are correct, and this is the next problem that he will encounter. However the error he is getting is with trying to access the `myBar` property; ie it throws the error before it even tries to do the `__invoke()` call.

Comment: yeah correct, thats why created a function with same name(of property).

Comment: Thank you @Harish for responding. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue as "return $this->arr_barmen[$barman_id] = new Barman();" is simply overwriting the barman who had previously been created by the myBar constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses. I devised a cute workaround as follows:

```
class Barman {  
    public function __construct() {
    }
    public function makeDrink() {
        return "vodka martini, shaken";
    }   
}

class Bar { 
    private $arr_barmen = array();
    public function __construct() {
        $this->arr_barmen['john'] = new Barman();
    }
    public function getBarman($barman_id) {
        return $this->arr_barmen[$barman_id];
    }
   public function __invoke($barman_id) {
      echo "I have been invoked \n";
      return $this->arr_barmen[$barman_id];
   }
}

class Foo {
    private $_myBar;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_myBar = new Bar();
    }
    // The fix
    public function myBar($barman_id) {
        return $this->_myBar->getBarman($barman_id);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$company = new Foo();
$drink = $company->myBar('john')->makeDrink();
echo $drink; // vodka martini, shaken
```

**How it works?**
Foo->myBar becomes private (Foo->$_myBar);

we create a public function with the name myBar inside Foo;

we create a "getBarman" fuction inside Bar which is called from Foo->myBar('john')

A few more steps - and now there's no ambiguity - Foo->myBar() IS always a function.

Cheers

M